# Clearing for each line

Tags: html, css

I use the following code to display a product.  **3 products per row**(each li is floated left)
The products are filtered with javascript also...
The problem is with div with class features... It is fixed height of some em.But i would like it not to be fixed height...If it is variable height then products at next rows wont be at the same y position .
The only solution i can figure is to add a clearer li..But that would require extra code for javascript when filtering products..
Any other idea ?

```
<li class="product f_manufacturerBreak_A_Way f_colorgrey ">
                <p class="title">Bolle Beaumont</p>
                <div class="imagePriceContainer">
                    <div class="imageContainer"><img alt="product" src="/photos/small/sunglasses/bol0112kk.jpg" width="100" /></div>
                    <div class="priceContainer">
                        <p class="price">130.00&#8364;</p>
                        <p class="priceNoDiscount">from <span>134</span></p>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <p class="action">Details</p>
                            <p class="action">Buy</p>
                        </div>    
                    </div></div>
                <div class="features">Sizes: S, L, XL<br />
    Colors: Black, Blue, Green, Red, White</div></li>
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? It's a bit unclear to me.

Comment: better to have not a screenshot, but full CSS of this example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could be at help?

http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Or you could try something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/PkFpr/

Comment: thank you That rocks.. It is great... Other developers suggested me that i should use tables.. Should i ?  Although i found that setting the first li clear left does the trick but tested that only on ie8,but this solution is superior

Comment: I like this solution since you can have a ul with dynamic width. With tables you'll have to decide how many columns you want, and thats final.